# Does C2 x C2 x C2 have a Klein-like name?

Tags: finite-groups, cyclic-groups

In my research I use these groups a lot:

**C2**, the cyclic group of order two.

**C4**, the cyclic group  of order four.

**C2 x C2**, the Klein group of order four, a.k.a V4.

**C8**, the cyclic group of order eight.

**C2 x C2 x C2**, *the Klein group of order eight(??)*.

Is there any problem with using

**C2, C4, V4, C8,** and ***V8(??)***,

as abbreviations in my papers?

I guess what the question really boils down to is if C2 x C2 x C2 is called something already and if not, would calling it the *"Klein 8-group, V8"* cause confusion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use any abbreviation you want, provided you explain it. Klein has EXACTLY one group, and it has 4 elements.

Comment: I've heard this called the "Elementary Abelian Group of Order 8"

Comment: Just call it $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ etc.